# Zabbix: how to parse error messages from web scenario checks as a macro

Tags: macros, zabbix

I just setup dozens of web scenario checks in Zabbix. I also added triggers and one action for all the triggers. To test the action I deployed a test bad web scenario check, however an email message I got from the test only gave very high-level information:

```
Problem: Service "Jira-QAS" is DOWN
------------​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​-------​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​-------​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​-------​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​----
Application: CloudOps
Problem started at 13:41:38 on 2019.11.20
Problem name: Service "Jira-QAS" is DOWN
Severity: High
Status: PROBLEM
Value: 1
Original problem ID: 2314429
----​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​-------​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​-------​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​-------​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​----
```

I want to parse "Last error message of scenario ..." as a macro and put it in the "default message" in "Action", so it would look something like this:

```
Problem: Service "Jira-QAS" is DOWN
----​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​-------​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​-------​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​-------​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​----
Application: CloudOps
Problem started at 13:41:38 on 2019.11.20
Problem name: Service "Jira-QAS" is DOWN
Severity: High
Issue: Couldn't connect to server: Failed connect to jira-qas.aws.ca:443; Connection refused
Original problem ID: 2314429
----​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​-------​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​-------​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​-------​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​----​​​​​​​----
```

I tried different macros such as {ITEM.VALUE}, {EVENT.STATUS}, but neither of them were good enough.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define Operational Data in the trigger, and add `{EVENT.OPDATA}` to the mail.

> Operational data allow to define arbitrary strings along with macros. The macros will resolve dynamically to real time data in Monitoring → Problems. While macros in the trigger name (see above) will resolve to their values at the moment of a problem happening and will become the basis of a static problem name, the macros in the operational data maintain the ability to display the very latest information dynamically.
> The same set of macros is supported as in the trigger name.

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/triggers/trigger